# Подсчитать количество строк кода javascript в файлах?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Какие есть программы с помощью которых можно подсчитать количество строк кода в файлах javascript? Ну и желательно еще какай нибудь анализ. 
Желательно максимально простую, где просто указываешь папку и всё.

Comment: первая ссылка в гугл https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc

Comment: А он считает строки в папках node_modules?

Comment: @manking а смысл в сторонних модулях? В ```Node``` есть ```fs```, что мешает написать самому пару-тройку строк кода? Количество строк в каком-то конкретном исходнике можно посчитать, например, так: ```fs.readFileSync('C:\\projects\\index.js', 'utf-8').split(os.EOL).filter(s => {return !!s}).length```, - ```filter``` можно убрать, если пустые строки также следует учитывать. По аналогии можно перебрать файлы в папке.

Comment: Времени нет. Конечно лучше самому написать модуль. Но хочется чтобы еще был представлен хороший анализ, какие доп фишки узнать про код, а не просто сколько там строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы подсчитать количество строк кода, нужно 
по совету @overthesanity
использовать npm sloc 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc

Чтобы исключить папку node_modules нужно написать такое выражение:

C:\inetpub>sloc ./bb --exclude node_modules

Где ./bb это папка в которой нужно произвести вычисления, а --exclude node_modules
нужно чтобы исключить папку node_modules

тогда будет выведена статистика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]